# Parsing XML element to get value of an element

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <i18nText><Country code="DE" language="de" text="nach Datum" /><Country code="US" language="en" text="by Date" /></i18nText>
```

I'm trying to get the value of the `text` element.There can be different values based on the `language` element.
How can i populate it into a dictionary ie: value of text for each language .

Comment: i would deserialize it into a type, then it's easy to use the data

Answer (score 1):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <i18nText><Country code=\"DE\" language=\"de\" text=\"nach Datum\" /><Country code=\"US\" language=\"en\" text=\"by Date\" /></i18nText>");
XmlNodeList countries = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Country");
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
for (int i = 0; i < countries.Count; i++)
{
     dict.Add(countries[i].Attributes["language"]?.InnerText, countries[i].Attributes["text"]?.InnerText);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var languageToText = XDocument
       .Parse(content)
       .Descendants("Country")
       .Select(p => new
       {
           language = p.Attribute("language"),
           text = p.Attribute("text")
       })
       .ToDictionary(
           p => p.language, 
           p => p.text);
```

Comment: Thanks.. i keep getting this exception `Exception Source:      System.Xml
Exception Type:        System.Xml.XmlException
Exception Message:     Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
Exception Target Site: Throw`

Comment: okay... thanks .. is there a way to add a unique id to the created dictionary ?

Comment: @techno What do you mean? The keys are unique by definition.

Comment: what is the key ?

Comment: @techno So please amend the question and give more details. Anyways, a declarative way to extract attributes and make a dictionary off of them is already provided. You can adapt it to your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Linq to Xml, it's more declarative and easier to read than using loops.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

        var xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF - 8""?> <i18nText><Country code=""DE"" language=""de"" text=""nach Datum"" /><Country code=""DE"" language=""de"" text=""nach Datum"" /><Country code=""US"" language=""en"" text=""by Date"" /></i18nText>";
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

        var dic = (from country in doc.Root.Elements()
                  select new { language=country.Attribute("language").Value, text=country.Attribute("text").Value }).
                  Distinct().
                  ToDictionary(country => country.language, country => country.text);
```